# MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT setting keeps being unset

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Occasionally I get this error in my logs:

```
WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'order_items.id' for query INSERT INTO `order_items` (`client_id`...
```

If I look at the table in phpMyAdmin the AUTO_INCREMENT setting on the ID field has been unset. So I switch it back on but then it'll happen again a few days later (after many successful operations on the same table).

This happens with other tables too. What could be causing this?

---EDIT---

The only thing I can think of is that the plugin which creates the table gets restarted every now and then. Here is the code:

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE `product_feeds` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` tinytext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `feed_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
  `last_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;";
  dbDelta( $sql );
  $sql = "ALTER TABLE `product_feeds`  ADD PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`);";
  dbDelta( $sql );
  $sql = "ALTER TABLE `product_feeds`  MODIFY `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;";
  dbDelta( $sql );
```

The last line is the line which adds the AUTO_INCREMENT. Is this the right order of statements?

Comment: What's the datatype of that field?

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran mediumint

Comment: what do you mean by set/unset?  AUTO_INCREMENT is gone from the column definition?

Comment: @ysth that's correct

Comment: that doesn't just happen.  something you are running is altering the tables or creating new ones.

Comment: I've just pasted in the table creation statement for you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, a column doesn't lose its AUTO_INCREMENT option spontaneously. It only happens when someone has run an ALTER TABLE to modify the column, and omits the AUTO_INCREMENT keyword.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int auto_increment primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> show create table mytable\G

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

OK so far...

```
mysql> alter table mytable modify column id mediumint;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table mytable\G

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Presto! The AUTO_INCREMENT option is gone!

If you modify the column, you must repeat the whole column definition, including options like datatype, default, NOT NULL, and yes, AUTO_INCREMENT, or else those options will be removed.

Now you have to figure out who is running ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've just pasted in my table creation statement. The last statement there adds the AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Something else besides the plugin initialization code must be running another ALTER TABLE, because the statements you showed should result in an auto-increment column if all three of the statements run. I'm not sure why they have been split into three statements -- I would have done it all in the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: I've searched the entire codebase for another ALTER statement and there are none. I'll try moving the statements into one (a previous developer did it this way for some reason)

Comment: Do you have the binary log enabled? You can dump it to a readable format and search for create/alter statements for that table. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog-row-events.html